# implement Unity3d inside a react-native app for augmented-reality

Tags: react-native, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality

I'm trying to load a Unity3d scene inside my React-native. this scene in unity is loading some dynamic 3d objects from cloud and uses Arkit/Arcore to detect the floor and place objects on the floor and so on. I can't use other solutions for AR because user can interact with 3d objects.

when user touch "see product in room" in the native app, the data for that specific 3d object will get passed into the unity scene, then unity scene (which is only an open camera) will take care of the rest until user touches close button.

is there any way to open Unity3d in react native and pass specific data for 3d object into into it?